# Gabor Filter implementation in Frequency domain

Tags: c#, image-processing, gabor-filter

[**Here**](https://github.com/primaryobjects/Accord.NET/blob/master/Sources/Accord.Imaging/Filters/GaborFilter.cs) we have the Spatial domain implementation of Gabor filter. But, I need to implement a Gabor filter in the Frequency Domain [for performance reasons.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140163/3804)

I have found the [Frequency Domain equation of Gabor Filter](https://www2.it.lut.fi/project/simplegabor/downloads/laitosrap100.pdf):

[image]

<sup>I am actually in doubt about the correctness and/or applicability of this formula.</sup>

***Source Code***

So, I have implemented the following   :

```
public partial class GaborFfftForm : Form
{
    private double Gabor(double u, double v, double f0, double theta, double a, double b)
    {
        double rad = Math.PI / 180 * theta;
        double uDash = u * Math.Cos(rad) + v * Math.Sin(rad);
        double vDash = (-1) * u * Math.Sin(rad) + v * Math.Cos(rad);

        return Math.Exp((-1) * Math.PI * Math.PI * ((uDash - f0) / (a * a)) + (vDash / (b * b)));
    }

    public Array2d<Complex> GaborKernelFft(int sizeX, int sizeY, double f0, double theta, double a, double b)
    {
        int halfX = sizeX / 2;
        int halfY = sizeY / 2;

        Array2d<Complex> kernel = new Array2d<Complex>(sizeX, sizeY);

        for (int u = -halfX; u < halfX; u++)
        {
            for (int v = -halfY; v < halfY; v++)
            {
                double g = Gabor(u, v, f0, theta, a, b);

                kernel[u + halfX, v + halfY] = new Complex(g, 0);
            }
        }

        return kernel;
    }

    public GaborFfftForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bitmap image = DataConverter2d.ReadGray(StandardImage.LenaGray);
        Array2d<double> dImage = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(image);

        int newWidth = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo(dImage.Width) * 2;
        int newHeight = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo(dImage.Height) * 2;

        double u0 = 0.2;
        double v0 = 0.2;
        double alpha = 10;//1.5;
        double beta = alpha;

        Array2d<Complex> kernel2d = GaborKernelFft(newWidth, newHeight, u0, v0, alpha, beta);

        dImage.PadTo(newWidth, newHeight);
        Array2d<Complex> cImage = DataConverter2d.ToComplex(dImage);
        Array2d<Complex> fImage = FourierTransform.ForwardFft(cImage);

        // FFT convolution .................................................
        Array2d<Complex> fOutput = new Array2d<Complex>(newWidth, newHeight);
        for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++)
            {
                fOutput[x, y] = fImage[x, y] * kernel2d[x, y];
            }
        }

        Array2d<Complex> cOutput = FourierTransform.InverseFft(fOutput);
        Array2d<double> dOutput = Rescale2d.Rescale(DataConverter2d.ToDouble(cOutput));

        //dOutput.CropBy((newWidth-image.Width)/2, (newHeight - image.Height)/2);

        Bitmap output = DataConverter2d.ToBitmap(dOutput, image.PixelFormat);

        Array2d<Complex> cKernel = FourierTransform.InverseFft(kernel2d);
        cKernel = FourierTransform.RemoveFFTShift(cKernel);
        Array2d<double> dKernel = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(cKernel);
        Array2d<double> dRescaledKernel = Rescale2d.Rescale(dKernel);
        Bitmap kernel = DataConverter2d.ToBitmap(dRescaledKernel, image.PixelFormat);

        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        pictureBox2.Image = kernel;
        pictureBox3.Image = output;
    }
}
```

<sup>Just concentrate on the algorithmic steps at this time.</sup>

I have generated a Gabor kernel in the frequency domain. Since, the kernel is already in Frequency domain, I didn't apply FFT to it, whereas image is FFT-ed. Then, I multiplied the kernel and the image to achieve FFT-Convolution. Then they are inverse-FFTed and converted back to Bitmap as usual.

***Output***

[image]

1. The kernel looks okay. But, The filter-output doesn't look very promising (or, does it?).
2. The orientation (**theta**) doesn't have any effect on the kernel.
3. The calculation/formula is frequently suffering from divide-by-zero exception up on changing values.

**How can I fix those problems?**

Oh, and, also,

- what do the parameters **α**, **β**, represent?
- what should be the appropriate value of **f**<sub>**0**</sub>?

---

**Update:**

I have modified my code according to **@Cris Luoengo**'s answer.

```
    private double Gabor(double u, double v, double u0, double v0, double a, double b)
    {
        double p = (-2) * Math.PI * Math.PI;
        double q = (u-u0)/(a*a);
        double r = (v - v0) / (b * b);

        return Math.Exp(p * (q + r));
    }

    public Array2d<Complex> GaborKernelFft(int sizeX, int sizeY, double u0, double v0, double a, double b)
    {
        double xx = sizeX;
        double yy = sizeY;
        double halfX = (xx - 1) / xx;
        double halfY = (yy - 1) / yy;

        Array2d<Complex> kernel = new Array2d<Complex>(sizeX, sizeY);

        for (double u = 0; u <= halfX; u += 0.1)
        {
            for (double v = 0; v <= halfY; v += 0.1)
            {
                double g = Gabor(u, v, u0, v0, a, b);

                int x = (int)(u * 10);
                int y = (int)(v * 10);

                kernel[x,y] = new Complex(g, 0);
            }
        }

        return kernel;
    }
```

where,

```
        double u0 = 0.2;
        double v0 = 0.2;
        double alpha = 10;//1.5;
        double beta = alpha;
```

[image]

I am not sure whether this is a good output.

Comment: Is the middle plot your Gabor filter in the frequency domain? It should look like a shifted Gaussian (i.e. away from the origin, which is the top-left pixel). In the spatial domain it will have complex values. And so does the filtered result. Did you display the magnitude?

Comment: Also, for performance reasons, you should be implementing the recursive algorithm in the spatial domain: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3318442_Recursive_Gabor_filtering -- this is much faster than the FFT.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, `Is the middle plot your Gabor filter in the frequency domain?` --- **Yes**. `Did you display the magnitude?` --- **Yes**.

Comment: Start with `f0= sizeX/4` or so. That should give you a Gaussian half-way between 0 and the Nyquist frequency. Alpha and beta are the sigmas of the Gaussian, the smaller they are, the more selective you are with frequencies, and the less selective spatially. Your 10 and 15 are fairly large, if `sizeX` and `sizeY` are 256. That is OK, but try with smaller values as well if you still get poor results.

Comment: Gabor is a adaptable filter, just like the Gaussian, the FFT, and many other filters. You apply it to each image row, then on the result, on each image column. What separable means in this case is that you can write the spatial-domain filter as the outer product of two 1D filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the equation for the Gabor filter that you found. The Gabor filter is a translated Gaussian in the frequency domain. Hence, it needs to have `u²` and `v²` in the exponent.

Equation (2) in your link seems more sensible, [but still misses a 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter):

```
exp( -2(πσ)² (u-f₀)² )
```

It is the 1D case, this is the filter we want to use in the direction θ. We now multiply in the perpendicular direction, `v`, with a non-shifted Gaussian. I set `α` and `β` to be the inverse of the two sigmas:

```
exp( -2(π/α)² (u-f₀)² ) exp( -2(π/β)² v² ) = exp( -2π²((u-f₀)/α)² + -2π²(v/β)² )
```

**You should implement the above equation with `u` and `v` rotated over θ, as you already do.**

Also, `u` and `v` should run from -0.5 to 0.5, not from `-sizeX/2` to `sizeX/2`. And that is assuming your FFT sets the origin in the middle of the image, which is not common. Typically the FFT algorithms set the origin in a corner of the image. So you should probably have your `u` and `v` run from 0 to `(sizeX-1)/sizeX` instead.

With a corrected implementation as above, you should set `f₀` to be between 0 and 0.5 (try 0.2 to start with), and `α` and `β` should be small enough such that the Gaussian doesn't reach the 0 frequency (you want the filter to be 0 there)

In the frequency domain, your filter will look like a rotated Gaussian away from the origin.

In the spatial domain, the magnitude of your filter should look again like a Gaussian. The imaginary component should look like this (picture links to Wikipedia page I found it on):

[image: Gabor, real part]

(i.e. it is anti-symmetric (odd) in the θ direction), possibly with more lobes depending on `α`, `β` and `f₀`. The real component should be similar but symmetric (even), with a maximum in the middle. Note that after IFFT, you might need to shift the origin from the top-left corner to the middle of the image (Google "fftshift").

---

Note that if you set `α` and `β` to be equal, the rotation of the `u`-`v` plane is irrelevant. In this case, you can use cartesian coordinates instead of polar coordinates to define the frequency. That is, instead of defining f₀ and θ as parameters, you define u₀ and v₀. In the exponent you then replace u-f₀ with u-u₀, and v with v-v₀.

---

The code after the edit of the question misses the square again. I would write the code as follows:

```
private double Gabor(double u, double v, double u0, double v0, double a, double b)
{
    double p = (-2) * Math.PI * Math.PI;
    double q = (u-u0)/a;
    double r = (v - v0)/b;

    return Math.Exp(p * (q*q + r*r));
}

public Array2d<Complex> GaborKernelFft(int sizeX, int sizeY, double u0, double v0, double a, double b)
{
    double halfX = sizeX / 2;
    double halfY = sizeY / 2;

    Array2d<Complex> kernel = new Array2d<Complex>(sizeX, sizeY);

    for (double y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
    {
        double v = y / sizeY;
        // v -= HalfY;  // whether this is necessary or not depends on your FFT
        for (double x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            double u = x / sizeX;
            // u -= HalfX;  // whether this is necessary or not depends on your FFT
            double g = Gabor(u, v, u0, v0, a, b);

            kernel[(int)x, (int)y] = new Complex(g, 0);
        }
    }

    return kernel;
}
```

Comment: You have totally removed sin(θ) and cos(θ) ? There are no trigonometric terms in your formula?

Comment: @anonymous: I simplified. Think of the `u` and `v` in this answer as the `uDash` and `vDash` in your code. That is, you rotate the u-v axes before using the equations I provide.

Comment: That said, I always use `α==β`, then the rotation is not necessary and everything is easier. Then instead of defining `f₀` and `θ` as parameters, you define `u₀` and `v₀`. In the exponent you then replace `u-f₀` with `u-u₀`, and `v` with `v-v₀`. That is, the frequency is defined in cartesian coordinates instead of polar coordinates.

Comment: This kernel seems to be unable to rotate.

Comment: The rotation comes from selecting `u₀` and `v₀`.